# Empty file is uploaded to S3 bucket when trying to save matplotlib piechart there

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, amazon-s3, boto3

So i want to create a matplotlib pie chart using some data then save it to BytesIO and send to my S3 bucket to store and use this picture later. No errors appear during the operation, its successfully uploaded on my S3 with correct name but the file's size is 0 and it is completely empty, though buf is not empty if i check it via print() before uplaod.

```
async def generate_pie_chart():
    slices = [33,33,33]
    fig = Figure()
    pie = fig.subplots()
    pie.pie(slices)

    buf = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf, format="png")

    S3_CLIENT.upload_fileobj(buf, S3_BUCKET, 'piee')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the following line right above `upload_fileobj()`:

```
buf.seek(0)
```

It moves the "cursor" to the beginning of the BytesIO. When `upload_fileobj()` is called, it can read/upload from the beginning of the file.

Comment: Yes! this fixes my issue! Thank you. But i got some extra question, i did upload few pictures to the s3 wihtout this .seek(0) and it went okay, though those prev iamges were larger in file size, would really appreciate if you can explain how this works)

Comment: I don't think it will work without `seek` unless `seek` is included in `savefig`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that previous images were regular PNG images translated to bytes not created by ```savefig()```